# Align $\displaystyle\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$

Tags: fractions

[image]
In $\displaystyle\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$. Is it possible to align $dx(t)$ with $dt$? Well, as I write it, it looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\hfill` in the denominator of the fraction to force left alignment if that is what you are looking for. You could also typeset the term a bit more balanced by having the `x(t)` outside the fraction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\frac{dx(t)}{dt\hfill}$
$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\big(x(t)\big)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: As @Zarko says, you can save yourself the `\displaystyle` command by using `\dfrac{}{}` from the `mathtools` package.

Comment: what about `mathtools` and `$\dfarc{dx(t)}{dt\hfill}$` or `$\dfrac{d}{dt} x(t)$` ?